# How can I connect to IBM MQ using SSL connection by C# IBMXMSDotnetClient

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I am currently able to connect to the IBM MQ server based on jndi binding file with the following c# code

```
    InitialContext ic = null;
    IConnectionFactory confac = null;
    IConnection conn = null;
    ISession sess = null;
    IMessageConsumer cons = null;
    IDestination dest = null;

    try
    {
        System.Collections.Hashtable env = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
        // Set the URL or PATH where the bindings file is located
        env[XMSC.IC_URL] = "file://c:/mqbindings/.bindings";
        // Initialize the context
        ic = new InitialContext(env);
        // Lookup for the connection factory name
        confac = (IConnectionFactory)ic.Lookup("myconfactoryname");
        // Create connection using the details from connection factory
        conn = (IConnection)confac.CreateConnection();
        // Create an auto ack session
        sess = conn.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
        // Lookup for the destination
        dest = (IDestination)ic.Lookup("myqueue");
        // ... rest of the code - create consumer or producer
    } 
    catch (XMSException xmsE)
    {
            // Handle exception
    }
```

However, when the SSL enabled in the IBM MQ Server, it fails to connect. Tried setting different properties (like setting XMSC.IC_PROVIDER_URL to the keystores directory/.jp12 file), but does not seem working.

Exception I got:

```
IBM.XMS.XMSException: 'CWSMQ0006E: An exception was received during the call to the method ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection: CompCode: 2, Reason: 2059.
```

I also cannot find any sample code on the official site on how this is working.

Any idea or sample code on this (not necessary in great details, at least, give me some ideas how what I need to set)?

Comment: Have you looked at the samples mentioned here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=client-sample-applications-implementing-tls-in-managed-net

Comment: Are you using unmanaged mode XMS.net framework,  managed mode XMS.net framework,  or XMS.net standard (core).  Which version of MQ are the dll files from? The answer to these questions will help me provide a accurate suggestion.

Comment: @MoragHughson Not aware of this before, will check

Comment: @JoshMc I am not quite sure about what is the difference among the different libs/versions you mentioned. I add the reference in NuGet. The name is IBMXMSDotnetClient with description = IBM® Message Service Client for .NET Standard (XMS .NET). It seems the core one you mentioned

Comment: @MoragHughson Checked and tried the sample code, it does not seems working. Still got the same exception (More info, the LinkedException is MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE). The exception does not seem to provide much useful info.

Comment: Are you running it on windows or Linux?

Comment: @JoshMc Client on windows and connecting to a remote MQ server

Comment: The cert would need to be stored in the windows key store, either the user or system.   The key repository name would need to be specified as either `*USER` or `*SYSTEM` depending on where you store it.   The friendly name of your cert needs to be either `ibmwebspheremq` + the user name you are running under in all lower case or you can provide the friendly name as the cert label, if you provide a cert label there are 2 bugs not fixed in a current version, the ccdt cert label is igored if set and if specified programmatically the case has to be lower no matter the case of the friendly name.